# Unable to get the innerHTML of a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to get the word thooty smotty from the following html

```
<div class="server-name">
                            thottysmotty                        </div>
```

i tried running the following query in the console - doucument.queryselectorall('.server-name').innerHTML
but i dont get any values wat wud be the correct statement.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll for correct format of the command.

Comment: since youre already using jquery use `$(.server-name).html()`. This will return the html, save it in a variable and use it

Answer (score 0):

`Document.querySelectorAll()` return a list of elements so you have to iterate through that list

```js
const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('.server-name');
for (const element of elementList) {
  console.log(element.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<div class="server-name">thottysmotty</div>
```

---

#### Reference

[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) *(Syntax > Return value)*

Answer (score 0):

In puppeter you can use [`page.$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) to retrieve innerHTML:

```js
const innerHtml = await page.$eval('.server-name', el => el.innerHTML)
```

In case of more elements with the same class name use [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) and iterate over the returned array of elements:

```js
const innerHtmlArray = await page.$$eval('.server-name', elements => elements.map(el => el.innerHTML))
```

On the Chrome console you can test it with: `$('.server-name').innerHTML` or `$$('.server-name')[i].innerHTML` (in case of the first matching element `i = 0`).